# How to generate random prime number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, primes, node-crypto

I am currently working on a JavaScript team project which involves cryptography.

I want my program to be as safe as possible, if possible industry-level safe, and as such I have been searching for community-approved implementations of random big prime number generation algorithms.

I explored Node.js Crypto, but I did not find a straightforward function that returns a random big probable prime number.

How can I use Node.js Crypto to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't comment on how cryptocragphically safe it is but if you want to keep within existing crypto libraries (good idea) you could generate a [diffie-hellman](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_creatediffiehellman_primelength_generator) object of specific length, then extract it's prime with [.getPrime](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_diffiehellman_getprime_encoding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[createDiffieHellman](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatediffiehellmanprimelength-generator) from Node's crypto module can do this:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

let DH = crypto.createDiffieHellman(16); // bit length

let prime = DH.getPrime('hex');
let dec = parseInt(prime, 16);

console.log('prime:', prime); // prime: c803
console.log('dec:', dec); // dec: 51203
```

Answer (score 6):

Since v15.8.0 Node.js built-in `crypto` module provides [generatePrime](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogenerateprimesize-options-callback) and [generatePrimeSync](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogenerateprimesyncsize-options) methods.

For example, to generate a 16-bit prime use:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let prime = crypto.generatePrimeSync(16, {bigint: true}); // 49597n
```

Since calculating large primes can take time, there is also an asynchronous option with a callback:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

crypto.generatePrime(16, {bigint: true}, (err, prime) => {
    console.log(prime); // 60757n
});
```

Note: the `bigint` option is used to return a `bigint` instead of an `ArrayBuffer`